How to disable SIM-card phone number autosuggestion in keyboard?
I faced a problem when I tried to use my app on Android 14. I started to mention that when I was typing a phone number into EditText, the keyboard would start to auto suggest me my SIM-card phone number. This was actually because of SIM-card, since then when I removed the SIM, the feature had stopped working.
The field which I use to fill with the phone number is a default EditText.
The autosuggestion looks like that:
SIM-card phone number autosuggestion in keyboard
I considered this feature to be redundant, so now I want to disabled it.
I tried to use the following attribute to adjust autofill:
android:importantForAutofill="no"
However, this didn't help...
How to resolve this?
